# add custom link to wordpress media gallery modal

Tags: php, theme-development, media-library

Is possible to add a custom field to the wordpress media-library popup? I want to link some images gallery to external links. I'm getting the images where I want to display it using `get_post_gallery_images()`. I'm not sure if a custom metabox can achieve this?

Comment: The [article](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/add-custom-fields-to-media-wordpress/) may help you to achieve the target.

Comment: Nice article, but it use an external plugin. I know ACF, but I can't use it for the project where I need to implement this ;(

Comment: check the [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-the-wordpress-media-uploader/) for custom implementation.